# How can I echo an output of a command that returns nothing/null?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to echo something from an output of a command that returns nothing.

This is the content of fnames.txt

```
company_TOYOTA_666_696969696*
company_FORD_123_435345666*
company_MAZDA_333_333333333*
company_HONDA_777_777777777*
company_FERARI_999_999999999*
```

This is my script to find each files in a line from fnames.txt:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r LINE
do
    output=$(find . -name "$LINE")

    if [[ $output ]];
    then
            printf "$output\n"
    elif [[ $output -eq 0 ]];
    then
            echo "$LINE Not Found"
    fi
done < /path/to/fnames.txt
```

But when I try to execute it, it only outputs the files it found not the elif statement that echo's the filename it didn't find:

```
./company_TOYOTA_666_696969696_11_22_33_4542352345.dat
./company_FORD_123_435345666_11_22_33_4542352345.dat
./company_MAZDA_333_333333333_11_22_33_4542352345.dat
./company_HONDA_777_777777777_11_22_33_4542352345.dat
```

I would like it to output this:

```
./company_TOYOTA_666_696969696_11_22_33_4542352345.dat
./company_FORD_123_435345666_11_22_33_4542352345.dat
./company_MAZDA_333_333333333_11_22_33_4542352345.dat
./company_HONDA_777_777777777_11_22_33_4542352345.dat
company_FERARI_999_999999999* Not Found
```

Comment: Using the bash shell gives the expected output.  I suspect you are using a different shell.

Comment: Double-quote your variables when you use them. For example, `"$output"` instead of plain `$output`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend leveraging `grep` and return codes to make life a little simpler.

```
while read -r LINE
do
    find . -name "${LINE}" | grep "${LINE}" || echo "${LINE} not found"

done < /path/to/fnames.txt
```

How this works:

- `find . -name "${LINE}"` pretty sure you know this one, find files in current directory that match `${LINE}`
- `| grep "${LINE}"` pipe the output to `grep`. We do this to produce a return value, which `find` does not normally produce a useful one. If the `grep` matches something, the match will be printed and the command returns 0. If nothing is matched, nothing is printed and it returns a non-zero return value.
- `|| echo "${LINE} not found"` The `||` is an OR pipe, if one of the commands before it returns non-zero it will be performed. So if the `grep` returns non-zero (i.e. no matching files were found) this echo is performed. If the commands before it succeed it will not be performed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-z` and `-n` string test operators:

```
String operators:

  -z STRING      True if string is empty.

  -n STRING
     STRING      True if string is not empty.
```

e.g.

```
while read -r LINE; do 
  output=$(find . -name "$LINE")
  if [[ -z "$output" ]]; then 
    echo "$LINE not found"
  else 
    echo "$output"
  fi
done < fnames.txt 
company_TOYOTA_666_696969696* not found
./company_FORD_123_435345666asdfgh
company_MAZDA_333_333333333* not found
./company_HONDA_777_7777777771242jkk
company_FERARI_999_999999999* not found
```

where

```
$ ls -1 company*
company_FORD_123_435345666asdfgh
company_HONDA_777_7777777771242jkk
```

Comment: `./company_TOYOTA_666_696969696_11_22_33_4542352345.dat`
`company_FERARI_999_999999999* Not Found`
`./company_FORD_123_435345666_11_22_33_4542352345.dat`
`company_FERARI_999_999999999* Not Found`
`./company_MAZDA_333_333333333_11_22_33_4542352345.dat`
`company_FERARI_999_999999999* Not Found`
`./company_HONDA_777_777777777_11_22_33_4542352345.dat`
`company_FERARI_999_999999999* Not Found`

This is the output. Not the result I'm looking for. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r LINE
do
    output=$(find . -name "$LINE" 2> /dev/null)

    if [[ -z $output ]]; then
        echo  "$LINE Not Found"
    else
        echo  "$output"
    fi
done < /path/to/fnames.txt
```

Comment: The `else` part should be `echo "$output"`.

Comment: It only prints the content of fnames.txt which is $LINE.